# How can I disable blog as landing page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm learning how to use wordpress using it from my computer as a local web server, and I want my website look like the preview of themes in the adding themes section, but after I install most of those themes, the first page I see is the post page. I want that any theme I install looks like Zerif Lite by example, that kind of look.

B.e. This real case: I just saw the Spacious theme, but when I click to preview just shows the blog section, and not the carrousel and all that desing...

This is my website http://ajfmo.ddns.net and i want tome make look this way http://demo.themegrill.com/spacious/

If anyone want to see inside my dashboard ask me by private message.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Settings=>Reading in the admin area and there is an option to choose a static page as your "home" page.

Comment: Hi @MikeR thanks for the advice, but when i do That it only shows the page that I set, and still can't see the desire main page, look at my links and you will find What I mean.